# What are the ways to speed up parsing in Antlr4?

Tags: python, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have some doubts regarding the performance of Antlr4.

1. I am currently using Python with Antlr4. It is terribly slow compared to Java (Verified using Antlr4 IntelliJ plugin). Since I need to work with bigger codes for parsing, I am planning to switch to a language which will be the fastest with Antlr (Eg: Java, C or Python). Any suggestions?
2. Any tips on optimizing the Antlr grammar for faster parsing (I am trying some online resources)
3. If I continue with Python itself, what are the best ways to speed up parsing? (Note: There is a suggestion in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455500/slow-antlr4-generated-parser-in-python-but-fast-in-java) to use the antlr4 available in  https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/pull/1010 for speed up). Has anybody tried it?

**UPDATE**

3. Using Antlr 4.7.1 from the github repo helped me in speeding up the parsing process in Python. (The parsing which took more than 3 hours and still unfinished with Antlr 4.5 which came with Ubuntu 16.04 got completed in 25 min or so  when I used Antlr 4.7.1 from github repo)

Comment: Which ANTLR version? If ANTLR 3, do you use any predicates / backtracking, or just plain LL(*) grammar? The former may lead to exponential complexity if used in a bad place, the latter should have linear complexity.

Comment: I am using Antlr4. I use +, ? etc. not only *. What does predicates and backtracking mean?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with v4, hopefully someone else will chime in. I believe predicates are no longer used in v4, but there might be some pitfalls in how v4 resolves non-LL decisions.